# Regarding Laravel Deployment without virtualhost in WAMP or LAMP

Tags: laravel, deployment

I have a query regarding laravel deployment, I have gone through many posts regarding this, and found out this deployment has been done through Laravel Forge and some other options on a shared hosting. For WAMP or LAMP, it has been done through virtual hosts

my query is: is it possible to work with Laravel for local development inside WAMP or LAMP without using virtual host like we can do it in codeigniter ?

thank you for your answer and time

Comment: Do you mean running Laravel project on local host without going through composer : php artisan serve?

Comment: @Michel , yes almost, I will use composer to have my files in www directory of wamp and then work in it like I do in codeigniter.

Comment: I have done it. Yes it's possible, never tried it with wampp, but I have with xampp. On a windows machine I did, and believe you can do it any other system. Install composer with Shell menu enable, then create a directory in xampp/htdocs/pojectFolder, right click projectFolder then click use composer here, after installing Laravel with "composer create-project laravel/laravel" of course u know it already. U should be able to run your project with localhost/projectFolder instead of localhost:8000 (composer way)

Comment: @Michel, thanks for your comment, yes I have done this too, let us assume the project directory is named as "blog" , now I can run then root page if I browse "http://localhost/blog/public", then the root page has been shown, as you have mentioned, but if I set a REST controller in route named 'api' and have a function name 'getLogin' , then browsing towards "http://localhost/blog/public/api/getLogin" yields a "Not Found" Error message.

Comment: U don't even need to put /public what u need is to configure you route. And I think that will also solve the issue with getLogin. 
In routes.php to show your home page u can do: Route::get('/', array('as' => 'index', 'uses' => 'YourController@index'));
So to create public function index(){
rerturn View::make('index');
} And also for login page :

Route::get('/getLogin', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'YourController@getLogin'));

public function getLogin(){
return View::make('yourLoginView');
}

Comment: Not working brother here.. still getting the not found error

Comment: I can't tell man. May be you need to show your code here for this 3 files: routes.php, yourController.php and the directory structure to your view file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81208/discussion-between-habibalsaki-and-michel).

Comment: I agree with habibalsaki. Please post your routes.php, yourController.php, and the directory tree.